# node-gyp Error cannot find module '/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js'

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

Why is it looking for node-gyp.js in an absolute path, when node-gyp itself is installed in /usr/bin/node-gyp?
If I do

```
find /usr -name node-gyp.js
```

the result is

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js
```

As it can be seen, I have node-gyp.js in two places. How can I direct node-gyp to search these places?

Comment: The places you're showing are dependency installs (part of another module; in both cases `npm`). How did you install `node-gyp`?

Comment: npm install node-gyp

Comment: I'm reading the install log, and at end there are errors. I will upload the log to http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues

Comment: Perhaps just upload the errorlog here to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

It was a node-gyp installation trouble. 
I was using an old version of npm; after upgrading npm, node-gyp installed successfully and runs ok.